# Class AB power amp DC bias at the emitter

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, dc, power-amplifier

I tried using KVL to prove that indeed the DC bias at the emitter of both Q1 and Q2 is Vcc/2.
The following assumptions I made are:
R1=R2
D1,D2 and the Base-Emitter diodes of both Q1 and Q2 are exactly match.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in my solution I end up with a contradiction. What am I missing?

Thank y'all!

Comment: Check the signs of both your Vbes, bearing in mind you have both PNP and NPN.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the emitter-base voltage of the PNP Q2 transistor is VEB which is -VBE. Is it wrong?

Comment: "the emitter-base voltage of the PNP Q2 transistor is VEB which is -VBE. Is it wrong?" - no, but the sum of NPN and PNP Vbe's is not 2Vbe.

Comment: @Paumdrdo Looking at your purple equation set, you change the sign of the 1st term of the 3rd equation, arbitrarily, when you should not. Look at the 1st term of the 2nd equation! Why do you change the sign going from the 2nd equation to the 3rd equation (purple?) Did you pick up the sign from the 1st equation, accidentally?

Comment: Notice that only one current is flowing then Vcc = I_R1 + Vd1 + Vd2 +I_R2 thus, I_R1 +Vd1 = Vd2+I_R2 = Vcc/2. So at a point when D1 cathode "meeting" with D2 anode we have Vcc/2 Therefore if Vd1 = Vbe1 and Vd2 = Veb2  the output voltage will also be equal to Vcc/2.  For example, if VCC = 12V and Vd = Vbe = 0.6V we have 6.6V at the T1 base and 5.4V at the T2 base. Therefore we have 6V at the combined emitters.